# How to open a SQL file with HeidiSQL with the console?

Tags: batch-file, file-io, heidisql

I'd like HeidiSQL to save my written SQL statements, when I close and reopen HeidiSQL; but I couldn't find any option for this, so I'm trying now to do this manually; save the queries as `.SQL` file in the interface and start the program with the `.sql` file. Even this doesn't work. If I open a `.SQL` file (by doubleclicking it), my database is shown, but it doesn't load the `.SQL` file. It opens it up only if I choose the file in the interface manually (Ctrl + O).

Some ideas?

In the end I'd like to have a batch file or something that does the job to open HeidiSQL with my SQL statements loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [doc](http://www.heidisql.com/help.php), I see this:

> Open multiple .sql files in query tabs:
>
> ```
> c:\path\to\heidisql.exe fileA.sql path\to\fileB.sql fileC.sql ...
> ```

So you can use that in a shortcut or script file to open a given file.

If you want the program to remember the last files you had open, however, well, I don't see that the session memory features of the program extend to last open files.  Feel free to make a suggestion to the authors, or, since its an open source program, you could make the additions yourself.

Comment: thanks for your research but exactly this doesn't work. It always just opens heidisql without the Querytabs this is what I tried: C:\Programme\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe test.sql I also tried to put two sql Files or the whole filepath. Always the same result.

Comment: The forum thread where restoring previously used query tabs is requested is here: http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=18072

Opening sql files per command line as stated in the help document works fine here. Are you sure you have the right file name + path, or does the path probably contain whitespaces?